# How to implement keyboard navigation with custom checkboxes in React

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, keyboard-events, wai-aria, tabindex

I am trying to create a custom checkbox that removes the checked icon and instead uses the text as the button. However, when I implement this, the keyboard navigation is removed. How can I bring back, or not get rid of keyboard navigation with a custom checkbox?

Note: I am using Formik to handle the validation and submission and Tailwind for the styling.

```js
<div
        key={index}
        className="rounded-md ring-offset-primary ring-offset-2 focus:ring-quad focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 flex gap-2"
      >
        <label htmlFor={player.name} className="cursor-pointer">
          <Field
            type="checkbox"
            onClick={() => handleSetChecked(index)}
            id={player.name}
            name="players"
            value={player.name}

            className="opacity-0 cursor-pointer hidden"
          />
          <span
            className={`block h-full py-1 px-2 rounded-md transition-all border-2 border-quad text-base ${
              checkedStatus[index] ? 'bg-quad text-primary' : 'bg-transparent'
            }`}
          >
            {player.name}
          </span>
        </label>
      </div>
```

Comment: Did you tried using `tabIndex` with some index value for keyboard navigation?

Comment: @Shiladitya I tried doing `tabIndex='0'`, but while they did navigate div's, I wasn't able to click enter or space to select that div.

Comment: You shouldn't be navigating divs, you should be navigating elements you can interact with. `tabIndex` should also be a number, not a string. Can you update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and perhaps also include a *running* codesandbox that we can inspect live?

Comment: @DrewReese is not accurate. While tabindex **is** a number, it's value is surrounded by quotes so `tabindex="0"` is correct. You'll also need a keyboard handler to trap on the keypress event and listen for space or enter and a handler for mouse clicks so the mouse user can check the box too.

Comment: @slugolicious Then it should be `tabIndex={0}` as `"0"` is a string, not a number. ***However***, after a quick test, `tabIndex={0}` and `tabIndex="0"` appear to both serialize to `tabindex="0"` in the DOM, so I suppose my statement wasn't entirely accurate, I'll give you that much. You're dead on about possibly needing a `keyPress` handler though.

Comment: @DrewReese everybody wins!